# MongoDB find expr with multiple eq

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, find, expr

This query which should filter results by the month seems to be working fine. But I can't figure out how to add a year filter as well.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 12]
  }
});
```

I tried to come up with something like this but no success.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 12] }, 
      { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$timestamp" }, 2018] }
    ]
  }
});
```

How to do that properly?

Answer (score 21):

I wanted to use find not aggregate. Adding another `$eq` with `$and` like this worked for me.

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    { $expr: {$eq: [{$month: "$timestamp"}, 12]} },
    { $expr: {$eq: [{$year: "$timestamp"}, 2019]} }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` instead of `find`.

A 3 step solution will work great:

1. `$project` the year and month fields together with the document itself, using `$$ROOT`. Since `$project` outputs only the specified fields, we will need to project the document itself as well.
2. Filter by the year and month you would like, using `$match`.
3. `$replaceRoot` to bring the original document back to the top level (flatten it).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "year": { "$year": "$timestamp" },
      "month": { "$month": "$timestamp" },
      "document": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 12
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$document" }
  }
])
```